# How to add custom UITabbar in iOS7GM using xcode5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

Hello i am begginer in iOS I have created custom tabbar and add UIbar button items which are work properly in iOS 6 but in iOS 7 GM and Xcode 5 It Show Problem.....
    This is my code for custom Tabbar ...

```
 TabBar=[[UITabBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 80)];
TabBar.autoresizingMask =UIViewContentModeTopRight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

TabBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];

UIButton *btn1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];


[btn1 setTitle:@"Charge Details" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn1.titleLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.0];


[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(ChargeDetails) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn1];

UIButton *btn2=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40,40)];
btn2.titleLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.0];
[btn2 setTitle:@"View Contact Details"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(ViewContactDetails) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn2];


TabBar.items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:button1,button2,nil];

[self.view addSubview:TabBar];
```

This Code work in iOS 6 successfully but in iOS 7 GM I have problem ..actually custom Tabbar add on view successfully but when we add barbutton items this show error ...in this line

```
  TabBar.items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:button1,button2,nil];
```

and this is error ....

```
   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem _updateViewForIdiom:positionItems:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbd3c6c0'
  *** First throw call stack:
    (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x04b9a5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018b58b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x04c37903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x04b8a90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x04b8a4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   UIKit                               0x006caefa -[UITabBar setItems:animated:] + 1218
6   UIKit                               0x006c9d9c -[UITabBar setItems:] + 48
7   HISWebService                       0x00021ee6 -[PatientLabDetailsViewController viewDidLoad] + 4566
8   UIKit                               0x0052e9a8 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
9   UIKit                               0x0052ec44 -[UIViewController view] + 35
10  UIKit                               0x00548a72 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 778
11  UIKit                               0x00555757 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
12  UIKit                               0x00556349 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
13  UIKit                               0x0068f39d -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
14  UIKit                               0x00485dd7 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
15  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018c781f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
16  QuartzCore                          0x03e1172a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
17  QuartzCore                          0x03e05514 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
18  QuartzCore                          0x03e05380 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
19  QuartzCore                          0x03d6d156 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
20  QuartzCore                          0x03d6e4e1 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
21  QuartzCore                          0x03d6ebb4 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
22  CoreFoundation                      0x04b6253e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
23  CoreFoundation                      0x04b6248f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
24  CoreFoundation                      0x04b403b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
25  CoreFoundation                      0x04b3fb33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
26  CoreFoundation                      0x04b3f94b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
27  GraphicsServices                    0x01ab59d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
28  GraphicsServices                    0x01ab57fe GSEventRun + 104
29  UIKit                               0x0041b94b UIApplicationMain + 1225
30  HISWebService                       0x0001f5fd main + 141
31  libdyld.dylib                       0x051be725 start + 0
32  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Please solve my problem how to add custom button on UITabbar in iOS 7 GM ....
Thanks In advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple's Tabbar documentation:

> A tab bar is a control, usually appearing across the bottom of the
>   screen in the context of a tab bar controller, for giving the user
>   one-tap, modal access to a set of views in an app. Each button in a
>   tab bar is called a tab bar item and is an instance of the
>   UITabBarItem class. If you instead want to give the user a bar of
>   buttons that each perform an action, use a UIToolbar object.
>
> The UITabBar class supports user customization of a tab bar by
>   reordering, removing, and adding items to the bar. You can use a tab
>   bar delegate to augment this behavior.
>
> Use the UITabBarItem class to create items and the setItems:animated:
>   method to add them to a tab bar. All methods with an animated:
>   argument allow you to optionally animate changes to the display. Use
>   the selectedItem property to access the current item.

You are using UIBarbuttonItems in a tab bar.  If you want to use a tab bar use UITabBarItems.

However, seeing that you are adding actions to the buttons, you should be using a toolbar, not a tab bar.  It should work peachy if you make these changes!